# JQuery Cascade Function not firing imediatly after change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

After a Ajax.BeginForm submit, dropdownlist cascade change() don't fire imediatly.

View that generate the new DropDownList:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.CreateAdCategoryTypeViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Ad.CreateAd(), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ad", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @id = "categoryTypeForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Category_Id)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CategoryType_Id)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryType_Id, Model.CategoryList, HeelpResources.DropdownlistCategoryFirstRecord)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryType_Id)
}
```

After a sumbit, the generated View is:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.CreateAdCarViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
    <legend>Car</legend>

   <div id="makes">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Make_Id)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make_Id, Model.MakeList, HeelpResources.DropdownlistMakeFirstRecord)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Make_Id)
    </div>
    <div id="models">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Model_Id)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, Model.ModelList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model_Id)
    </div>        
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

At this point I have a cascade function to fire when Make change to fill Model list:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#Make_Id", function () {
        $('#Make_Id').cascade({
            source: "/Ad/ListModelByMake",
            cascaded: "Model_Id"
        });
    });
});
```

Cascade function:

```
// Cascade function
(function ($) {
$.fn.cascade = function (options) {
    var defaults = {};
    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            var params = {};
            params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
            $.post(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                //$.getJSON(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                opts.childSelect.empty();
                if (opts.firstOption != "")
                    opts.childSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', '-1')
                            .text(opts.firstOption));
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    // alert(opts.firstOption);
                    opts.childSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', item.Id)
                            .text(item.Name)
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Unfortunatly, it only works after a second change on the Makes Dropdownlist, any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Charlietfi, I was able to solve this problem, here is the solution:

In the Ajax.Form we need to add an OnSucess call to define the cascade function:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Ad.CreateAd(), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ad", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "createAdCategoryTypeOnSucess" }, new { @id = "categoryTypeForm" }))
```

Then in an external JS file, we can define the cascade definition:

```
function createAdCategoryTypeOnSucess() 
{
    $("#Make_Id").cascade({
        url: "/Ad/ListModelByMake",
        paramName: "makeId",
        firstOption: '',
        childSelect: $("#Model_Id")
    });
}
```

Like this, the event is fired right after the dropdown change.

Thanks again charlietfl ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a change handler to initiate the plugin. The plugin code binds a change handler to the element.

Since you are calling plugin within a change handler, the change handler of the plugin won't fire until the next time select is changed because the initial change event has already occurred.

Change code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        $('#Make_Id').cascade({
            source: "/Ad/ListModelByMake",
            cascaded: "Model_Id"
        });   
});
```

Comment: It's still not working. The event don't detect the change on the dropdownlist. Don't forget that the Make Dropdown is a result of a Ajax.Begin form PartialView result and "injected" into a div. This may be the cause? The event don't know about the new DOM object? In the moment of the javascript inclusion in the code, the dropdown object don't exist. He has to be able to detect the future object in the code.

Comment: will have to call the plugin withing success callback of AJAX ..after it is inserted then

Comment: If I would need to have it on a document.ready function (because I have a case where the OnSucess don't know about the view that is coming and some don't need the cascade action activated) of the loaded view? I put a test if ($("#Model_Id").length) to load it if it exists, it seems a good aproach to you?

Comment: could set different success handlers for different controllers based on url or other variable you set up. If `#Make_Id` doesn't exist when you call it, it won't cause any problems either

Comment: How can you set diferent OnSucess functions in the Ajax.BeginForm based on the Form's URL?

Comment: use `attr('action') to get url from form